# cursor: copy not working in Internet Expoler

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am applying css cursor:copy for a given div.  In case of FF and Chrome browser it's working fine,  but when I am opening it in IE(version 9+) its not working .
Please suggest 
Below is code  -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>

<style>
    .editable{
        color: #428bca;
        cursor: copy;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
This is my editable div

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually my problem is to override cursor for editable area . there is an editable area ,once cursor is coming on editable div its showing 'Text' cursor .Unable to override this property for IE .. any suggestion or workaround

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `cursor: copy` is not supported until IE 10.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: even Chrome (Mac) is not working well too. the copy cursor blinks. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/b9unq6m4/)

Answer (score 0):

well after lots of research and workaround finally I  have implemented a workaround.By default I make contenteditable = false and at run time on click I am making it true.Which full fill my requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use an workaround using a cursor png image and change your css like below

```
.editable{
        color: #428bca;
        cursor: url(cursor.png), auto;
    }
```